# Secure Authentication rest api

Tags: java, html, rest, authentication, ws-security

I have my html basic form and java server(REST) side and MYSQL as my database.
I want to implement a secured authentication login form plus after login every rest api's must be called by the valid users only.

What are the points to consider for developing secure login page? One thing i know is login api must be an POST method. What are the other points needs to be taken care? 
Where to save the state of the logged in user so that immediate calls can be verified using that state. Is it to be client side or server side? If on server side then that violets the RESTlet principles
Am i require to store the encrypted password in the database? If yes then which encryption algorithm is best?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you should split your question into at least two: 1) how to secure REST endpoints, 2) what is the proper method to store a password in database. As for REST: are you using RESTlet or another framework (Jersey, Spring Web) ?

Comment: Ok. I'm using RESTlet for rest apis.